# Why is my HTC Incredible's WiFi so slow?

Tags: htc-droid-incredible

I have a Droid Incredible rooted with Cyanogen 7.

When I use my network wi fi (on cable modem) the download speed is about 400kb/s, using SpeedTest.net's Droid app. When I test with my Virgin MObile LG Optimus V I get 8.5 Mb/s.

I've turned off bluetooth (which I hear uses the same radio as wi fi).

Comment: Do you see the same performance on other WiFi networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is embarrassing but I'll leave it here for posterity anyway.

Tried another network and got slightly better performance (probably b/c the hotspot had weak signal strength).

After more investigation I realized that it was connecting to my network then disconnecting. Turns out **the password was wrong**, but rather than actually telling me that, it just connected and then a few seconds later (after I'd left that screen) it disconnects.